# Got new HDD so and downloaded Android SDK. Making new project gives 100+ errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Today I downloaded Android SDK together with Eclipse. I ran Android SDK Manager and let him download every API. When I wanted to actually do something I went in Eclipse and made a new project. Program gave me aroun 108 errors and console showed this:

```
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-10-20 19:17:59 - reewwww] D:\AndroidProjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
```

There is way more than this but I there is limitation of how much characters post may contain. Anyone knows anything that may be causing this? I already tried to redownload it once again but it aint helping.

Here is my android application settings:

```
Minimum Required SDK: API 11 Android 3.0
Target SDK: API 18 Android 4.3
Complie With: API 18 Android 4.3
Theme: Holo light with dark action bar.
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have some android  5.0 code

Comment: Hmm I just noticed that most of the errors come from appcombat_v7 part. But I don't think I can just get rid of it.

Comment: If your project uses AppCompat, you have to add it to your Project build path. Let me know.

Comment: It is already there.

Comment: having this issue for days now. I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Uhh, I tried searching for it but I couldn't find anyone with that problem. It is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday i update android sdk and support repository, and some of my idea projects become full of this errors.
So here what i tried:

1. change target to 21 in project.properties file
2. change  to 21 in my pom.xml file
3. change project sdk in project settings to 21

don't know which step was needed, but eventually project start build

Comment: Thank you. I had to use latest "Compile With" otherwise it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

appcompat_v7 is Google's package,which can make Android2.1 and above use the UI of4.0.

When you new a project,select the minimum SDK to Android 4.0 or above.Then you won't use the package.Therefore,the errors won't appear

I solved my problem by this method successfully!

Forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing in gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
```

and compile / target sdk to 19